# Quick question about Arrow operators

Tags: haskell, arrows

Say I've got `f :: u -> v -> w` and `g :: x -> y -> z`.  What I want is `h :: (u,x) -> (v,y) -> (w,z)`.

So I could go about this manually:

```
h (u,x) (v,y) = (f u v, g x y)
```

But where's the fun in that?

Using `(***)` I can get partway there:

```
(f *** g) :: (u,x) -> (v -> w, y -> z)
```

But I can't figure out how to get that final mile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
(***) :: (Arrow a) => a b c -> a b' c' -> a (b, b') (c, c')
```

So specialize a to `->` and we get:

```
(***) :: (Arrow a) => (b -> c) -> (b' -> c') -> (b, b') -> (c, c')
```

And that's great, except we want to, for whatever reason, take the first two arguments as a single pair instead. But that's easy, we just uncurry.

```
Prelude Control.Arrow> :t uncurry (***)
uncurry (***) :: (Arrow a) => (a b c, a b' c') -> a (b, b') (c, c')
```

And if you specialize the `a` again, you should see the type signature you were looking for.